# PHP 7 | chr() + strict_types === error?

Tags: php, php-7

I try to convert my working PHP 5.x code into an more modern PHP 7.x code-base, so I added "declare(strict_types=1);" in the first step, but it didn't work as expected.

code: `ord(chr(ord("\xE9") / 64) | "\xC0");`

demo: https://3v4l.org/680ts

github: https://github.com/voku/portable-utf8/blob/master/src/voku/helper/UTF8.php#L6613

PHP < 7.0 or > 7.0 (without strict_types=1) === **195**

PHP > 7.0 (with strict_types=1) === **192**

Maybe someone can explain this to me? I think it's because of "chr()" expecting an integer, but we get a float?! But there isn't any warning or something like this...? -> http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.strings.hex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, let's break it down.

```
ord("\xC0");
```

That's 192. With or without strict types. The breakdown is happening here

```
chr(ord("\xE9") / 64)
```

Now `ord("\xE9") / 64` works out to 3.640625 and we can see [where it breaks down here](https://3v4l.org/AXv55)

```
var_dump(ord(chr(3.640625)));
```

This is `0` with strict types, and `3` without. Per [the manual for `chr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php)

```
string chr ( int $ascii )
```

So the result here is a `float`, not an `int`. What's happening is that strict types cannot convert the `float` to an `int`, so it passes a `0`

[Per the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict)

> In strict mode, only a variable of exact type of the type declaration will be accepted, or a TypeError will be thrown. **The only exception to this rule is that an integer may be given to a function expecting a float.**

We're going the other way. So strict types behaves like all PHP when you pass it a bad argument

```
var_dump(ord(chr('bob'))); // string 0, in all PHP versions
```

Comment: Nice breakdown and explanation.

Comment: I've noticed that from version 7.4, PHP started to throw "Fatal error" in this case.